# How to prevent a form action opening a new tab with the linked php script?

Tags: php, forms, action

I have a simple input form with a submit button on my website

```
  <form action="signup.php" method="post" name="form">
      <div class="input">
             <input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="NAME@EXAMPLE.COM">
             <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="submit">
     </div>
     </form>
```

The entered text is written to a text document with the signup.php script

```
    <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
             $email = $_POST['email'];
            $file = fopen("signup.txt","a+");
            fwrite($file,$email);
            fclose($file);
            print_r(error_get_last());
    }
    ?>
```

Everything is working fine. But whenever the submit button is clicked a new, blank tab opens to the php script. How can I get rid of this and replace the input form with some kind of feedback?

Comment: Does it open a new tab, or is the same tab just becoming blank after the post? It should not open a new tab without target="_blank" in <form>

Comment: Is there any Javascript on the page?  I don't see anything here that would do that.

Comment: Does not open a new tab in my browser

Comment: is there any html in signup.php? Awesome looking site btw!

Comment: The same tab is becoming blank. I don't want anything to happen except the display a user feedback on the original page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see, you are pointing to blank php page with script, that's why you get blank page after pressing submit.
  Second thing is that your if statement is wrong.

Best for you would be to put everything in same page named signup.php

I would do it like this :

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post" name="submit">
      <div class="input">
             <input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="NAME@EXAMPLE.COM">
             <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="submit">
     </div>
     </form>

<?php
            if(isset($_POST['email']))
    {
             $email = $_POST['email'];
            $file = fopen("signup.txt","a+");
            fwrite($file,$email);
            fclose($file);
            if(error_get_last() == null) echo "<p>Your signup was recorded</p>";
            else print_r(error_get_last());
                }
?>
```

and you can add any class to that paragraph to have it look how you want it and positioned where you want it.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Im not sure I understand.

Add the html to the php script and take it out in the index.html file? How do I then place the form on my page?

Comment: @Tobi if your file is called index.html, just rename it to index.php.  the html will still work, and add this php script i wrote to your page, and change form action to index.php. Cause that's where it will land again after submiting. But one question, why are you saving it to .txt file. It would be much easyer to use database.

Comment: Just figured this out. Thanks! Im using this to teach myself. Thought about starting with a txt, then moving on to databases. Just want to get it right first.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use html in your .php file under the ?> and it will render it. Try:

```
<p>Thank you for subscribing</p>
```

You should upgrade that to match the beautiful design you have on the first page tho.

EDIT:

You can also do something like

```
if(error_get_last() == null) echo "<p>Thanks for subscribing</p>";
else print_r(error_get_last());
```